# Xubuntu menulibre application (menu editor) not launching

Tags: xubuntu, menu

My cat was recently laying on my computer when I was trying to edit the xubuntu menu using the Menu Editor application (menulibre). My cat messed around with some stuff so when I tried to go back into menulibre to try to fix it, it would not open. I got an error for the first two times that I opened it that said that it quit unexpectedly, but I can not get that again, so I can not say what it said. The rest of the times that I tried to open it, I got no error, so I opened up the task manager, and tried to open it again. I opened it, and it appeared in the task manager for a few seconds in red and then went away. So then I tried to open it from the terminal by typing `menulibre` and I got this error:

```
** (menulibre:2819): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-d2bt58fVXP: Connection refused
**
ERROR:/build/buildd/gnome-menus-3.10.1/./libmenu/gmenu-tree.c:4022:preprocess_layout_info: assertion failed: (!directory->preprocessed)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Thanks in advance :D

## EDIT:

I have tried restarting my computer multiple times but I have still not gotten a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First backup the menus

```
mv ~/.config/menus/ ~/.config/menus.bak
```

Then open menulibre and your problems are solved. :)

Comment: Still a valid solution in 2022!